Create Safe with enabled Modules
I've been trying to create a safe with some modules pre-enabled so we don't have to pass an approval for the safe to enable them.
We want to achieve whis with solidity, so the safe-core-sdk is out of the picture.
After some research I found out that is recommended to use the delegate call when the safe is created in addition to the MultiSend contract.
So, I've been able to create the safe using the SafeProxyFactory and the createProxyWithNonce the problem comes when I try to encode the transactions for the MultiSend contract. The transactions that need to enable the module must have the safe address as the value of to, however we still dont have the address of the new safe to encode the transactions correctly.
The resulting address can be predicted if we know the creatorAddress(address(safeProxyFactory)), the creationCode and the salt used. We have the first param, the second one is given by the proxyCreationCodefunction and the salt is suposedly the same as given to the createProxyWithNonce function.
After trying this transactions were still failing and came to the conclussion that the predictedAddress wasnt alright. So I looked into the proxy creation function and I saw that the salt used by the SafeProxyFactoryis in fact:
bytes32 salt = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(keccak256(initializer), saltNonce));

This means that if we want to predict the address we the same salt used by the SafeProxyFactory, this wouldn't be a problem if the salt didn't depend on initializer which in this case is contains the encoded call to the multiSend function of the MultiSendcontract. The problem comes when this encoded data must contain the address of the safe to call enableModuleand since the salt depends on the data, the generated address for the safe also depends on the data but at the same time the data depends on the address of the safe so I cannot see a way of doing this with the information that I foundon previous questions or in the documenteation.
Can this really be done? Am I missing something?
Thank you for your time
Best, Jose

UPDATE
Hey, I managed to do it using the SafeModuleContract.sol as you mentioned. I tried to do a MultisendCall and worked as long as I only send one, if I try to concatenate multiple txs it starts reverting
This works:
bytes memory transaction1 = ...
bytes memory multiSendData = abi.encodeWithSignature(
  "multiSend(bytes)",
  transaction1
);


Being multiSendDatade data used in the delegateCall when creating the safe
This doesnt:

bytes memory transaction1 = ...
bytes memory transaction2 = ...
bytes memory transaction3 = ...

bytes memory transactions = abi.encodePacked(
  transaction1,
  transaction2,
  transaction3
);

bytes memory multiSendData = abi.encodeWithSignature(
  "multiSend(bytes)",
  transactions
);

---
### Solved

Solved using `bytes.concat` not sure why it failed with `encodePacked` probably something wrong with the encoded data


A similar question (deploying a safe + enabling safe modules in a single transaction, using only Solidity) has been answered here. Hope it can solve your issue as well!
If not please let me know  Best, Louis

It seems that the SafeModuleSetup.sol is the piece that I was missing. Will do a couple tests and let you know.
Thank you very much for your answer
